# sed: use regex to replace '<' char with '&lt;' in many XML files

Tags: xml, regex, sed, well-formed

I have thousands of non well-formed XML files to patch up.

Many of them contain the following issue: `<someTag attr='text [< 99]'/>` (note left angle in square brackets).

I would like to write a sed expression to replace all instances of `[<` with `[&lt;` for *.xml.

`sed -n 19p myFile.xml` returns `<someTag attr='text [<99]'/>` as expected.

`echo '[<45' | sed -n '/\[</p'` returns `[<45` as expected.

However, `sed -n '/\[</p' myFile.xml` returns nothing so apparently I need a different syntax when using that expression against a file as opposed to echo.  What syntax do I need to use?

Also, once I have this done, my plan is to do something like

`sed -i -n 's/correct expression/\[&lt;/g/p' *.xml` to run it against all matches in all files and output the new version to help me debug.  Does that seem reasonable?

BTW, sed seemed like the tool to use, but I'm perfectly fine using any other solution that runs on Linux.

Thanks!

Comment: The example you gave, `sed -n '/\[</p' file`, seems to work fine for me.  I'm using the terminal in OS X 10.7.

Comment: You're right.  I sed'd line 19 into a separate file and then couldn't match it. At that point, I went crazy.  When I copied and pasted the offending item into a text editor, though, I realized that '(' and '[' look identical on this crappy VT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, `sed -n '/\[</p' myFile.xml` returns nothing so apparently I
>   need a different syntax when using that expression against a file as
>   opposed to echo.

Hm, works for me:

```
echo '[<45' > test.xml
sed -n '/\[</p' test.xml
```

returns `[<45`.

That said, if you want to replace, do something like

```
sed 's/\[</[\&lt;/g'
```

For example, to modify all xml files directly, do

```
sed -i 's/\[</[\&lt;/g' *.xml
```

(the -i switch is for directly modifying the files; otherwise, their contents will be sent to stdout)

> Does that seem reasonable?

Sure, that is what sed is for.

Comment: Yeah...just a combination of '(' looking identical to '[' on this old virtual terminal.  Oh, well. :)

Comment: FYI:  You said `sed 's/\[</[\&lt;/g'`.  I'm guessing you meant `sed 's/\[</[\&lt;/g' *.xml`?  Given that the terminal is hard to read and '(' looks like '[', I changed that to `sed 's/(</(\&lt;/g' *.xml` and it doesn't actually change the affected files.  Did I misinterpret?

Comment: Yes, I only gave you the basic option. Use -i to replace the files in place (just like you wrote in your question).